# unable to transfer data of data attribute of dynamically created selection box

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I'm trying to create a dynamic selection box with data attribute that will be passed on an input box, attached here is a code snippet of the code.

I cant seem to make it work. Whenever i change the first select box the other input box is being affected by it, and at the same time the value of the input box should be based on the data attribute of the selected text box.

all script are declared at the bottom of the page, is there any alternative way to do this?

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box box-default">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Report Per Office</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Code</th>
              <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">General Description</th>
              <th rowspan="2"><button type="button" name="add" id="add">ADD</button></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <input type="text" name="account_code[]" class="form-control account_num" readonly>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select class="form-control" data-live-search="true" name="account_name[]" required>
                  <option></option>
                  <option value="Accounting" data-acc="100">
                    Accounting
                  </option>
                  <option value="Budget" data-acc="200">
                    Budget
                  </option>
                  <option value="Treasuary" data-acc="400">
                    Treasuary
                  </option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1;
    var chart_add = '<tr id="row_chart' + i + '"><td align="center"><input type="text" name="account_code[]" class="form-control account_num" readonly></td><td><select class="form-control" data-live-search="true" name="account_name[]" required><option></option><option value="Accounting" data-acc="100"> Accounting</option><option value="Budget" data-acc="200">                 Budget</option><option value="Treasuary" data-acc="400">                        Treasuary </option> </select></td><td><button type="button" name="remove_chart" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger remove_chart">REMOVE</button></td></tr>';
    $('#add').click(function() {
      i++;
      $('#dynamic_field').append(chart_add);
      $('select[name="account_name[]').change(function() {
        $('.account_num').val($('select[name="account_name[]"] option:selected').data('acc'));
      });
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.remove_chart', function() {
      var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
      $('#row_chart' + button_id + '').remove();
    });

  });
</script>
<script>
  $('select[name="account_name[]').change(function() {
    $('.account_num').val($('select[name="account_name[]"] option:selected').data('acc'));
  });
</script>
```

Comment: How is this different to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664810/cant-get-proper-data-from-data-attribute-of-a-select-box-populated-with-php)?

Comment: Please fix the errors in your snippet first. You appear to be missing a `selectpicker` plugin

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function",  try to fix this error

Comment: sorry about that, i already fix the snippet problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to replace this:**

```
$('select[name="account_name[]').change(function() {
    $('.account_num').val($('select[name="account_name[]"] option:selected').data('acc'));
});
```

**with this:**

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="account_name[]', function() {
    $(this).parent().prev().children('.account_num').val(($(this).data('acc'));
});
```

Comment: I have not tried it yet. But you can consider my solution. Or you can search something likes: *select specific previous element Jquery*

Comment: I think if you use my solution and take some changes in your code, it will work fine.

Comment: thank you for your time.. i finally did it.. i still use the same solution but different approach.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var scntDiv = $('#p_table');
var i = $('#p_table tr').size() + 1;

$('#addRow').click(function() {
    scntDiv.append('<tr><td align="center"><input type="text" name="account_code[]" class="form-control output'+i+'" readonly></td><td><select class="form-control" name="account_name[]" onChange="'+"$('.output"+i+"').val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('price'))"+'"><option></option><option value="Accounting" price="100"> Accounting</option><option value="Budget" price="200">                 Budget</option><option value="Treasuary" price="400">                        Treasuary </option> </select></td><td><a href="#" id="remRow">Remove</a></td></tr>');   
    i++;
    return false;
});

//Remove button
$(document).on('click', '#remRow', function() {
    if (i > 2) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
    <a href="#" id="addRow">Add</a>
</h2>
<table class="dynatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Account</th>
            <th>Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="p_table">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                      <input type="text" name="account_code[]" class="form-control output" readonly>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <select class="form-control" name="account_name[]" onChange="$('.output').val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('price'))" >
                      <option></option>
                      <option value="Accounting" price="100">
                        Accounting  
                      </option>
                       <option value="Budget" price="200">
                        Budget  
                      </option>
                       <option value="Treasuary" price="400">
                        Treasuary  
                      </option>
                    </select>
                    </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```